# Levelling up and good strategy for Ingress?

Tags: ingress

I am very new to gaming and even newer to Ingress.

I'm hoping for some pointers in the right direction of how to move up in the world and how to deal with an area that is predominantly reigned by the opposition?

As a noob what strategies are recommended? In terms of poker and cards I'm more the type for sitting back and waiting for the right opportunity rather than risky business.

Answer (score 5):

Ingress is a multi-player team game. A single player can only make so much of a difference in this game, regardless of their level.

- The only way to get 4 mods on a portal is for at least two players to deploy mods on it as a single player can only deploy two mods.
- The only way to get a max-level portal is to have 8 players deploy a level 8 resonator on it as a single player can only deploy a single level 8 resonator.
- A single player can't recharge fast enough to keep a portal from being destroyed, but multiple players can keep up with the damage (lag-permitting).

The fastest way to level and the recommended way to play, at all, is as a team. In my cell, we have a few players that diligently watch the COMM for new players and invite them to a Google Hangout dedicated to helping new players level. If you haven't had anyone invite you, then I'd recommend attempting to contact an active player (whose name you see on portals nearby you) and ask them if such a Hangout exists or if they are willing to help you level.

When you first start the game, you are very incapable of doing anything. You can get AP from "dirty hacking" (hacking the portals of the opposite faction), but you take damage for every hack. You can also destroy very weak portals, deploy on already destroyed portals, or link unlinked portals, but that requires you to have very opportunistic timing.

However, if you get into a group of experienced players, they understand the importance of helping new players, especially in hostile territory. They will do the hard work for you and then let you get as much easy experience as possible until you are able to hold your own. They'll also provide you with items to help you advance for when you are on your own.

Just a few sessions with experienced players can get you leveled quickly, teach you a lot of game concepts you don't yet know, give you an idea of the history of your region in the game, introduce you to the more well-known players in the area, as well as make some connections and build friendships.

The sooner you can get in touch with other agents in your area, the sooner you'll *really* be playing!

Answer (score 2):

Koviko explained the advantages of team playing. However, here are some tips for low level solo playing:

- On Ingress Intel Map zoom close enough to see [grey Level 0 portals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPFux.png) (i.e uncaptured portals) in your area. If you capture and fully deploy it (place resonators on each of the 8 available slots) you get a total of 1750 AP.
- After a few levels you can also play around with Level and Health filters to find [weak anchors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ULL.png) – portals, that are nodes to control fields. If you go and destroy its resonators, you gain 750 AP for each destroyed field plus additional AP for destroyed links and resonators. Prefer portals that have no shields under MODS tab and when destroying resonators, walk around to find a spot directly on them to have maximum impact.
- Also [this Ingress FAQ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZKt6bvgcsS4Bzve8k36FZNmAYrwt8QrSn-wztNpOkhU/edit) answers most of the questions about game mechanics you didn't even know you had.